# ruby's Parallel assignment to assign same value over simple assignment

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment

Is there a difference between:

1.

```
> lines, codelines, total_lines, total_codelines = 0, 0, 0, 0
=> [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

2.

```
> lines, codelines, total_lines, total_codelines = 0
=> 0
```

If yes, then which of them should be used in what situations?

[edit]
there is also a third way:

```
    lines = codelines = total_lines = total_codelines = 0

> lines = codelines = total_lines = total_codelines = 0
=> 0
irb(main):016:0> lines
=> 0
irb(main):017:0> codelines
=> 0
irb(main):018:0> total_lines
=> 0
irb(main):019:0> total_codelines
```

In case of arrays

```
0> a = b = { }; a[:a] = 6
=> 6
irb(main):023:0> b = 3
=> 3
irb(main):024:0> a
=> {:a=>6}
irb(main):025:0> a = 10
=> 10
irb(main):026:0> b
=> 3
> a.object_id
=> 21
irb(main):028:0> b.object_id
=> 7
```

Comment: There's also `lines = codelines = total_lines = total_codelines = 0` but you need to be careful with shared reference problems when you do that.

Comment: ^^shared reference problems?

Comment: Play with `a = b = { }; a[:a] = 6` you'll see the problem.

Comment: ^^I tried but saw no difference. post updated with results :s

Comment: What does `b` look like after `a[:a] = 6`?

Comment: ^^6 as its the same object, `a.object_id = 76456630` & `b.object_id = 76456630` but when I change the `b`(as seen in the above post), they become different objects. how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference.

1.

```
lines, codelines, total_lines, total_codelines = 0, 0, 0, 0
```

has as many values on the right side as there are variables on the left. Each value will be assigned to each variable.

2.

```
lines, codelines, total_lines, total_codelines = 0
```

does not have as many values on the right side as there are variables on the left. The missing values will be supplemented as `nil`. `lines` will become `0`, the rest will become `nil`. There is no reason you should use assignment like this.

A typical case when you want to use multiple variables with less number of values on the right is when you have an array that you do not know how many elements it has.

```
a, b, *c = some_array
```

In the case above, depending on the length of `some_array`, `a`, `b`, `c` will  have different things assigned.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between those two is that the second example is only assigning `0` to `lines`.

```
lines, codelines, total_lines, total_codelines = 0,0,0,0

codelines #=> 0
```

Whereas when the amount of rvalues in the parallel assignment is smaller than the amount of lvalues:

```
lines, codelines, total_lines, total_codelines = 0

codelines #=> nil
```

The surplus values are assigned with `nil`

So, the second type of parallel assignment does not really make sense unless you need to initialize a variable with `nil` in a particular scope; for example a counter outside an iteration.